# odds of a digit missing from a 30 digit number

Tags: probability

I'll get your computer to pump out a random 30 digit decimal number (leading zeros permitted, each digit randomly and independently selected). If somewhere in that number, all the digits 0 to 9 show up, then I give you a dollar. But if any digit is missing (e.g. the digit 5 doesn't show up in the 30 digit number) you give me $2.

Repeat as often as you like.

Would you be inclined to take me up on it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Have you tried something to solve this problem? Please show your reasonings and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

We shall work out the expected value of this game, if it is positive we should be willing to play forever and if negative or $0$ then not.

This is a classic example of the [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) principle.

Denote $A_i$ as the event the number does not contain the digit $i$. For $i = 0,1,2,\dots,8,9$

Hence $\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{i=0}^9 A_i] $ is the probability at least one digit is missing.

$\mathbb{P}[\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_{a_i}] = (\frac{10-n}{10})^{30}$ for any injective sequence $a_i$

Hence $p:=\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{i=0}^9 A_i] =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{10}{k}(\frac{10-k}{10})^{30} \approx 0.370$

And so the Expected value of this game is $1\cdot(1-p) - 2\cdot p \approx - 0.113 <0 $

And so we should not want to play this game.